# Glitch Geany in Ubuntu 18.04, scroll bar, how to solve it?

Tags: 18.04, scrollbar

I have glitch in Geany (version 1.32), Ubuntu 18.04. The scroll bars become completely orange over the entire width (or height), and this makes it difficult to use for its intended purpose.
Is it possible to solve it?
Terminal shows this errors:

```
(geany:9576): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:34:04.511: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(geany:9576): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:34:04.511: Negative content height
-11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(geany:9576): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:34:04.511: Negative content width -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node scrolledwindow, owner GtkScrolledWindow)

(geany:9576): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:34:04.511: Negative content height -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node scrolledwindow, owner GtkScrolledWindow)

(geany:9576): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:34:04.511: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar

(geany:9576): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:34:04.511: gtk_widget_get_preferred_width_for_height: assertion 'height >= 0' failed

(geany:9576): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:34:04.511: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width 12 and height -28

(geany:9576): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:34:04.511: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar
```

[image]

Comment: Was this an upgrade to 18.04 or a clean install?

Comment: This was clean install.

Answer (score 3):

You could download and make install the latest geany from official site:
https://www.geany.org/download/releases/
After I install the v1.35, this problem could be resolved. 
(Remember to remove v1.32 before make install v1.35)

Comment: Instead of a manual installation, one can also go with the geany ppa: 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geany-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install geany geany-plugins-common

Comment: Instead of PPA, just download and install the official packages from Ubuntu 19.10, they're compatible with the libraries of the 18.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/geany and https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/geany-common

Comment: I have the same problem, but I already have the latest version v1.36 installed. Had it both on Ubuntu Bionic and now on Focal, any other resolution that could help here?

Comment: Thanks, v1.37 does resolve the problem, although the scroll bar is still slightly diminished when out of focus.  At least it is visible and usable now.